# fancybox галерея

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Проблема с библиотекой fancybox до этого не работал с ней поэтому не могу понять в чем ошибка (при клике на ссылку происходит обычный переброс на картинку без использования fancybox). Вот код

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.galery__item").fancybox({
    "padding": 20,
    "imageScale": false,
    "zoomOpacity": false,
    "zoomSpeedIn": 1000,
    "zoomSpeedOut": 1000,
    "zoomSpeedChange": 1000,
    "frameWidth": 700,
    "frameHeight": 600,
    "overlayShow": true,
    "overlayOpacity": 0.8,
    "hideOnContentClick": false,
    "centerOnScroll": false
  });

})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384- 
    DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<body>
  <header class="header">

    <div class="section6">
      <div class="section6__title">
        Галерея
      </div>
      <div class="section6__galery">
        <a href="images/IMG_7337.png" class="galery__item" rel="group"><img src="images/IMG_7337.png"></a>
        <a href="images/IMG_7661.png" class="galery__item" rel="group"><img src="images/IMG_7661.png"></a>
        <a href="images/IMG_7352.png" class="galery__item" rel="group"><img src="images/IMG_7352.png"></a>
        <a href="images/IMG_7872.png" class="galery__item" rel="group"><img src="images/IMG_7872.png"></a>
        <a href="images/IMG_8038.png" class="galery__item" rel="group"><img src="images/IMG_8038.png"></a>
        <a href="images/IMG_7723.png" class="galery__item" rel="group"><img src="images/IMG_7723.png"></a>
        <a href="images/IMG_8052.png" class="galery__item" rel="group"><img src="images/IMG_8052.png"></a>
        <a href="images/IMG_7412.png" class="galery__item" rel="group"><img src="images/IMG_7412.png"></a>
      </div>


      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: вы показали код, но не указали, что в нем работает не так, как вы ожидаете

Comment: вообще ничего не работает, возмодно подключил неправильно библиотеки, если код правильный то буду разбираться с подключением

Comment: @ilyaaa521 какая версия fancybox и что говорит консоль ?

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js

Comment: jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).fancybox is not a function TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/DNS/Desktop/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0/test%205/script.js:9:21)
    at l (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29375)
    at c (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29677) undefined   // это ошибка в консоле

Comment: jquery.fancybox.min.js:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.fancybox.min.js:12  // еще такая ошибка

Comment: а вы ссылки на jquery и fancybox на страницу не забыли вставить?

Comment: Вот посмотрите , файл выше подредактировал , полностью исходник с подключенными библиотеками

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для [fancybox 3](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) достаточно прописать `data-fancybox="group"` +  у Вас jquery подключение идет после подключения плагина, а должен быть перед всеми jquery плагинами:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.1/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

 <header class="header">

    <div class="section6">
        <div class="section6__title">
            Галерея
        </div>
        <div class="section6__galery">
            <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502200893034-b7bca90610ef?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=c081e2fd522f3c6e53fdf4b47aeb0943&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" class="galery__item" data-fancybox="group">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502200893034-b7bca90610ef?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=c081e2fd522f3c6e53fdf4b47aeb0943&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" >
            </a>
            <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505533321630-975218a5f66f?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=c5f38d8a09b82ab5bf6f0c87b1fb2877&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" class="galery__item" data-fancybox="group">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505533321630-975218a5f66f?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=c5f38d8a09b82ab5bf6f0c87b1fb2877&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" >
            </a>
            <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499240713677-2c7a4f692044?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=0d316ec72f7ff56be6e6f33de946fcaf&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" class="galery__item" data-fancybox="group">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499240713677-2c7a4f692044?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=0d316ec72f7ff56be6e6f33de946fcaf&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" >
            </a>
        </div>
     </div>
 </header>
```

Comment: Подключение библиотеки выше плагина помогло в плане ошибок в консоле но сейчас другая проблема, при нажатии на элементы галереи, открывается не pop-up а в самом низу страницы отображаются элементы

Comment: Вообщем всем спасибо, тут надо было подключить еще fancybox.css, подключил все заработало!